# Phoenix Framework (Elixir) - Loading JS files into the asset pipeline

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

So I've gotten angular to work with Phoenix, but when I try moving my controllers to separate files under web/static/js/controllers, they aren't loaded. I'm guessing this has to do with Brunch but I'm not sure... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!
Firstly, I replace Brunch.io with Gulp (you can find a good guide for that here - http://bryaninspired.com/phoenix-0-10-with-gulp-and-jspm/)
The second problem I was having was with jspm not loading the packages I installed. The problem here was that in config.js I gave absolute paths instead of relative paths:

`paths: {
    "github:*": "/jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "/jspm_packages/npm/*"
}`

Now it loads up AngularJS just fine, as well as any JS files I put in web/static/js, including subdirectories. 
Now let's just see if it is able to load my Angular HTML files....

**Edit**
It seems that loading Angular is one thing, but actually *running* my Angular code doesn't work... I'm trying to figure out why... I think it has to do with SystemJS or Gulp.
The strange thing is that non-angular code (like just a simple `console.log` in a test.js file) runs just fine. Anything inside `angular.module('blah',[]).whatever` just doesn't seem to run.....

**Edit #2 - FIXED!** It seems that I forgot to add the following to my JS

`angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['ApplicationName']);
});`

Don't forget to bootstrap angular on document ready!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem myself before. I believe it has something to do with Brunch yes. Have you tried running `mix phoenix.digest`?

If I recall correctly, if you move your files to `priv/static` it should work (instead of them being on the Web directory), but I don't think this is the proper way.

Comment: I've tried `mix phoenix.digest` but I'll have to read more about it because it didn't seem to do much...
I'll try moving to `priv/static`, but like you said - I'm not sure that's the proper way. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: If you find the answer please post back. I also have this problem in a project of mine, but still haven't had the time to look into it.

Comment: Well, I've found a solution but it's not very elegant.... in app.js you can do `import testcontroller from './controllers/test_controller'` without `export` in the actual controller JS file (which is named test_controller.js, notice in app.js you don't write the .js extension) 
But like I said - this isn't the most elegant solution, as I would like to auto-load files in a dir, instead of specifying each one...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a solution but it's not very elegant.... in app.js you can do
 `import testcontroller from './controllers/test_controller'` 
without export in the actual controller JS file (which is named test_controller.js, notice in app.js you don't write the .js extension) But like I said - this isn't the most elegant solution, as I would like to auto-load files in a dir, instead of specifying each one...